# Can Windows 7 connect to Mac Wifi server?

Tags: windows, macos, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I created a Wifi network with my Mac and I could see it on Windows 7 as well as connect to it but when I launch my browser it doesn't work: server not found.

Can Windows 7 work with Mac OS X's Wifi or did I miss something?

I tried the other way round it doesn't work either :(

Comment: Are you just creating an Adhoc Wifi Network or using Mac OS X's Internet Sharing?

Comment: @Chealion I can't see the difference in Sys Prefs. The only thing worth noting are the password schemes allowed, I believe Internet Sharing doesn't allow WPA2.

Comment: @tobylane: Yes, there is a difference in terms of types of passwords - Internet Sharing also turns on NAT and DHCP.

Comment: Chealion go into your network sharing center on your windows machine and right-click the network adapter that you are using. See if there are any specific wi-fi settings you have enabled such as IP/DNS. This must be interfering with the connection since you are connected. Wi-Fi works on every device regardless of the operating system

Comment: I think your expectations are the problem. Creating a WiFi network just creates a network. It doesn't provide Internet access to machines on that network.

Answer (score 0):

It should just work fine. Check if the WiFi connections on both Windows and the Mac are granted access to be shared the internet connection with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i do it every day at home, no specific options to set.

Answer (score 0):

might be a problem with WINS, make sure its set to domain or workgroup on the mac according to if your windows Pc is on a domain or workgroup.

Answer (score -1):

Go to `System Preferences > Sharing > Internet sharing > WiFi Options` and change the `Security` option to `WPA2 personal`.